# NameError: uninitialized constant on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Rails 5 application with some modules/classes located under `/lib`. In development I can access those through the rails console like so:

```
irb(main):001:0> MyClass.do_something
```

In Production on Heroku I get this:

```
irb(main):001:0> MyClass.do_something
NameError: uninitialized constant MyClass
```

As you might have guessed I autoload the `/lib` directory in my application.rb:

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```

However, the most curious thing about this is, that I can access this class from rake tasks. So something like this works fine:

```
task do_something: :environment do
  MyClass.do_something
end
```

Which tells me that the class is present on Heroku.

Any ideas?

Comment: `MyClass` runs - but outside of your rails application...

Comment: @LiroyLeshed Alright, but that doesn't explain why it runs in the dev console but not in the Heroku console...

Comment: what if you run `rails c production` locally and try calling your class?

Comment: @nattfodd Same error as on Heroku. Do you know what the problem is?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rails doesn't autoload in production for thread safety, instead eager loading application constants. You can fix your issue by using the `eager_load_paths` method instead.

```
config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```

If you still want to autoload in development you can make it conditional

```
load_path_strategy = Rails.env.production? ? :eager_load_paths : :autoload_paths
config.public_send(load_path_strategy) << Rails.root.join('lib')
```

If you *really* need autoloading of this directory in production you can set `enable_dependency_loading` to `true`.

```
config.enable_dependency_loading = true
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```

See [this blog post](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/08/29/rails-5-disables-autoloading-after-booting-the-app-in-production.html) for more explanation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I have been puzzled why all of my objects were uninitialized constant in console on heroku in production. In my local production, they were fine.

Turns out that the problem was that I was running: "heroku run console" not "heroku run rails console".

Worth noting that when you access console from the heroku website, the same problem occurs there too. Wasted a lot of time on this.